# How am I supposed to define a left associative operator in a LL(1) grammar?

Tags: parsing, operators, grammar, parsec

So I was asked to create a LL(1) grammar for some language, that has operators with different priorities. I could easily implement the rules for all the operators except for the left associative ones. For example, part of my grammar is like this:

```
A -> A and B | A or B | B
```

This is clearly ambiguous. How could I transform this in a way that it is not ambiguous, so it is a LL(1) grammar, while the operators remain left associative?

I tried something like this, but A1 it's still ambiguous.

```
A1 -> A1 A2 | B

A2 -> and B | or B
```

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Are you actually using the Parsec combinator library?

Comment: It's not ambiguous, just left-recursive. `A -> A and A | B` would be ambiguous.

Comment: You want to have `something` that is made of: `something` followed by `others`. That is a left recursive construction. You cannot have a left associative grammar that is not left recursive (with other words: the left associative grammars are left recursive). The left recursive grammars cannot be handled by the LL(1) parsers. That means that you cannot do it. You can escape the problem by using: `a = b {or b}; b = c {and c}; c = 0|1` and during parsing create the tree to be left associative. Here `{}` is a repetition from zero to infinity.